# Email confirmation "from" field is not working

Tags: php

The following is code on my site for sending a confirmation email when the user signs up.  The email gets sent just fine but the sender is blank (it comes up as "unknown sender").  I would like it to come from my email, from ABC Technologies.

```
{
// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------
// send e-mail to ...
$to=$user;
// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";

// From
$header="from: ABC Technologies";
// Your message
$message="Confirmation link for college match site\r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
$message.="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/chat_site/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header, "-f ABC Technologies");
}
```

Comment: Use proper mail headers. Your `From:` should be an Email address.

Comment: Even though a headache to read: Section 3.4 of http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, this is not a valid sender:

```
$header="from: ABC Technologies";
```

You're obviously missing the email address:

```
$header="from: ABC Technologies <abc@example.com>";
```

Additionally, this is not a valid return path:

```
"-f ABC Technologies"
```

Now you need an email address; not even an email+name combination, just an email:

```
"-fabc@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$headers  = "From: ABC Technologies < mail@example.com >";
```